# Is there a second order differential wave equation that only allows a finite set of discrete eigenvalues?

Tags: waves, differential-equations

I tried constructing a second order differential wave equation that only allows a finite set of discrete eigenvalues by using the power series expansion such as

\begin{align}
A_{j+2}
=
\dfrac{j-m}{(j+1)(j+2)-n(n+1)}
A_{j}
\end{align}
to obtain the follwing wave equation
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
-
\dfrac{n(n+1)}{x^2}
=
x
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}
-
m
,
\end{align}
where $n$ is any integer and $m$ is the eigenvalue in question. I realized that this equation does not force $m$ to be bounded for finite discrete values, because given a maximum value of $j_{
\text{max}}$, one can work the recursion backwards if $m$ is greater than $j_{
\text{max}}$.

Does this suggest that it is not possible to construct a second order differential wave equation that only allows a finite set of discrete eigenvalues?

Comment: Do you mean a discrete spectrum regardless of the boundary conditions? And why don't you have time dependence? Btw, I think this might go to Math.SE.